# Where can I find a proof for existence of eigenvalues for the Sturm-Liouville problem?

Tags: reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sturm-liouville

I am looking for a full--proof to refer to. I have an extracted copy of Boyce & Di Prima's book on differential equations "Elementary Differential Equations", specifically on the section on Sturm-Liouville problems.

In the book, is says "*we assume without proof that this problem actually has eigenvalues and eigenfunctions*" and adds that "The proof may be found in the references by *Sagan*(chapter 5) or *Birkhoff and Rota*(Chapter 10)"

I cannot find which book by either of those authors it is referring to. So I have searched online but while there are copious amounts of proofs for eigenvalues in the context of matrices, none were found for Sturm-Liouville problems.

No one seems to have done it online; is it unbelievably long or complicated? If anyone knows either which book the reference is talking about or, websites which provide the proof, it would be great if I can be directed there.

*I don't know what the best tag for this question is, so please edit/modify if you have better tags to put on

Comment: Birkhoff, G., and Rota, G.-C., Ordinary Differential Equations (4th ed.) (New York: Wiley, 1989). Sagan, H., Boundary and Eigenvalue Problems in Mathematical Physics (New York: Wiley, 1961; New York: Dover, 1989).

Comment: Have you studied compact operators?

Comment: no, i haven't studied that

Comment: How about equicontinuous families of functions? Or Complex Analysis? If you respond, be sure to use the @TrialAndError to ping me.

Answer (score 0):

The Sturm-Liouville problem is precisely the linear transformation problem- the only difference is that you need to show that the Sturm-Liouville operator is a **self-adjoint** linear operator.  What is the definition of "adjoint" in the case of second order differential operators?

Comment: so, given a linear operator $L$(lagrange's identity, in the Sturm Liouville case), an adjoint operator would be $L^*$ satisying $(Lu,v)=(u,L^*v)$ for some functions $u,v$, yes? And self adjoint would mean $L=L^*$. I'm just wondering if you mean that $L$ is taken as some matrix..? It would be great if you can elaborate some more on what you've hinted